# Combine dictionaries based on the value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this

```
[{"Name": John, "Score": 1}, {"Name": John, "Score": 2}, {"Name": Steve, "Score": 3}, {"Name": Steve, "Score": 4}]
```

How can I combine these dictionaries like this?

```
[{"Name": John, "Score": [1,2]},{"Name": Steve, "Score": [3,4]}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [{"Name": "John", "Score": 1}, {"Name": "John", "Score": 2}, {"Name": "Steve", "Score": 3}, {"Name": "Steve", "Score": 4}]

out = {}
for d in lst:
    out.setdefault(d['Name'], []).append(d['Score'])

out = [{'Name': k, 'Score': v} for k, v in out.items()]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'Name': 'John', 'Score': [1, 2]}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Score': [3, 4]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

using itertools

```
def combine(group):
    out = {}
    out['Name'] = group[0]['Name']
    score = []
    for sub in group:
        score.append(sub['Score'])
    out['Score'] = score
    return out

grouped = map(combine,[list(v) for k,v in groupby(x, lambda x: x['Name'])])
print(list(grouped))

[{'Name': 'John', 'Score': [1, 2]}, {'Name': 'Steve', 'Score': [3, 4]}]
```

Comment: there's probably a cool reduce function you could use to eliminate the combine